# JavaScript replace

Tags: javascript

In the following code, the `alert(a)` inside the JavaScript replace function will alert the matched strings, which, in this case, will be {name} and {place}.

This works as described by the documentation [javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) , namely, the first argument to the function in the replace method will be the matched string.  In the code below, the `alert(b)` will alert 'name' and 'place' but without the curly braces around them.

Why is that? How does it strip the curly braces for 'b'? Here's a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/KeHdU/

Furthermore, looking at this example from the docs,

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string){
  // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
  return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
};
```

Which of the parameters in this example would the 'b' in function(a,b) of the replace function below represent?

Part of my failure to understand might be due to the fact that I'm not sure what javascript does, for example, with the second parameter if the maximum number of arguments aren't used.

**code**

```
var subObject = {
    name:  "world",
    place: "google"

}; 

var text = 'Hello, {name} welcome to {place}';


var replace = function (s, o) {
            return s.replace(/\{([^{}]*)\}/g,
              function (a, b) {
                  alert(a);
                  alert(b);
                var r = o[b];

                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
              }
            );
}; 

var replacedText = replace(text, subObject); 
alert(replacedText); ​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the entire string matched by your regex (capturing groups don't matter, so it becomes `{name}`).

The second, third, fourth, etc. parameters are your capturing groups and since you only have one, your second argument becomes `name`.

The last two parameters are the position of the match and the entire string. You can omit these arguments from your callback if you'd like.

Here's a slightly more readable version of your code that accounts for attributes that aren't present in your replacement object:

```
var replace = function(string, object) {
    return string.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, function(match, group) {
        return group in object ? object[group] : match;
    });
};
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KeHdU/4/**

Comment: so the curly braces aren't part of the capturing groups (and therefore not included in argument b) because they're not in the parentheses?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: Yep. The parentheses include everything that you want to capture. You can have multiple sets of parentheses.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: Here's a quick demo. It should be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/KeHdU/5/

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum number of arguments isn't used, they are ignored. But if the arguments within the function are referenced and not tested first for !undefined, the script will error out.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace on how to use a replacement function

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string){
    // p1 is nondigits, p2 digits, and p3 non-alphanumerics
    return [p1, p2, p3].join(' - ');
};
```

> match: is the entire matched substring (ie what matched the regex)
>
> p1, p2 .... pn: are `The nth parenthesized submatch string` (within your matched substring)
>
> offset: offset in the original string
>
> string: input string

in your case you didnt supply the full arguments

```
s.replace(a, b /*, offset, string*/)
```

so `a=match` and `b=p1`

** Note that the function will be invoked multiple times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in the first parameter is global.

So each match begins with `{` and ends with `}` and you have 1 capturing parenthesis that matches the content inside the braces.  Also since you are using a global match /{([^{}]*)}`/g`

Therefore, the function is invoked twice on the 2 matches with the following parameters:

1. '{name}', 'name', 7, 'Hello, {name} welcome to {place}'
2. '{place}', 'place', 25, 'Hello, {name} welcome to {place}'

and the entire match (ie the first parameter) is replaced with the return value of the  function